# Множественный <select> на PUG

Tags: pug

Пытаюсь написать выпадающий список национальностей на PUG. Знаю что для сокращения нужно использовать цикл. Но никак не получается скомпилировать чтобы подставлялись значения массива в код html. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```
+e('select')#nationality.select(name='nationality')
  - var nationalityList = [
 {
 title: ['Afghan', 'Albanian', 'Algerian', 'American', 'Andorran', 'Angolan', 'Antiguans', 'Argentinean', 'Armenian', 'Australian', 'Austrian', 'Azerbaijani', 'Bahamian', 'Bahraini', 'Bangladeshi', 'Barbadian', 'Barbudans', 'Batswana', 'Belarusian', 'Belgian', 'Belizean', 'Beninese', 'Bhutanese', 'Bolivian', 'Bosnian', 'Brazilian', 'British', 'Bruneian', 'Bulgarian', 'Burkinabe', 'Burmese', 'Burundian', 'Cambodian', 'Cameroonian', 'Canadian', 'Cape Verdean', 'Central African', 'Chadian', 'Chilean', 'Chinese', 'Colombian', 'Comoran', 'Congolese', 'Costa Rican', 'Croatian', 'Cuban', 'Cypriot', 'Czech', 'Danish', 'Djibouti', 'Dominican', 'Dutch', 'East Timorese', 'Ecuadorean', 'Egyptian', 'Emirian', 'Equatorial Guinean', 'Eritrean', 'Estonian', 'Ethiopian', 'Fijian', 'Filipino', 'Finnish', 'French', 'Gabonese', 'Gambian', 'Georgian', 'German', 'Ghanaian', 'Greek', 'Grenadian', 'Guatemalan', 'Guinea-Bissauan', 'Guinean', 'Guyanese', 'Haitian', 'Herzegovinian', 'Honduran', 'Hungarian', 'I-Kiribati', 'Icelander', 'Indian', 'Indonesian', 'Iranian', 'Iraqi', 'Irish', 'Israeli', 'Italian', 'Ivorian', 'Jamaican', 'Japanese', 'Jordanian', 'Kazakhstani', 'Kenyan', 'Kittian and Nevisian', 'Kuwaiti', 'Kyrgyz', 'Laotian', 'Latvian', 'Lebanese', 'Liberian', 'Libyan', 'Liechtensteiner', 'Lithuanian', 'Luxembourger', 'Macedonian', 'Malagasy', 'Malawian', 'Malaysian', 'Maldivan', 'Malian', 'Maltese', 'Marshallese', 'Mauritanian', 'Mauritian', 'Mexican', 'Micronesian', 'Moldovan', 'Monacan', 'Mongolian', 'Moroccan', 'Mosotho', 'Motswana', 'Mozambican', 'Namibian', 'Nauruan', 'Nepalese', 'New Zealander', 'Nicaraguan', 'Nigerian', 'Nigerien', 'North Korean', 'Northern Irish', 'Norwegian', 'Omani', 'Pakistani', 'Palauan', 'Panamanian', 'Papua New Guinean', 'Paraguayan', 'Peruvian', 'Polish', 'Portuguese', 'Qatari', 'Romanian', 'Russian', 'Rwandan', 'Saint Lucian', 'Salvadoran', 'Samoan', 'San Marinese', 'Sao Tomean', 'Saudi', 'Scottish', 'Senegalese', 'Serbian', 'Seychellois', 'Sierra Leonean', 'Singaporean', 'Slovakian', 'Slovenian', 'Solomon Islander', 'Somali', 'South African', 'South Korean', 'Spanish', 'Sri Lankan', 'Sudanese', 'Surinamer', 'Swazi', 'Swedish', 'Swiss', 'Syrian', 'Taiwanese', 'Tajik', 'Tanzanian', 'Thai', 'Togolese', 'Tongan', 'Trinidadian/Tobagonian', 'Tunisian', 'Turkish', 'Tuvaluan', 'Ugandan', 'Ukrainian', 'Venezuelan', 'Vietnamese', 'Welsh', 'Yemenite', 'Zambian', 'Zimbabwean'],
 value: ['afghan', 'albanian', 'algerian', 'american', 'andorran', 'angolan', 'antiguans', 'argentinean', 'armenian', 'australian', 'austrian', 'azerbaijani', 'bahamian', 'bahraini', 'bangladeshi', 'barbadian', 'barbudans', 'batswana', 'belarusian', 'belgian', 'belizean', 'beninese', 'bhutanese', 'bolivian', 'bosnian', 'brazilian', 'british', 'bruneian', 'bulgarian', 'burkinabe', 'burmese', 'burundian', 'cambodian', 'cameroonian', 'canadian', 'cape verdean', 'central african', 'chadian', 'chilean', 'chinese', 'colombian', 'comoran', 'congolese', 'costa rican', 'croatian', 'cuban', 'cypriot', 'czech', 'danish', 'djibouti', 'dominican', 'dutch', 'east timorese', 'ecuadorean', 'egyptian', 'emirian', 'equatorial guinean', 'eritrean', 'estonian', 'ethiopian', 'fijian', 'filipino', 'finnish', 'french', 'gabonese', 'gambian', 'georgian', 'german', 'ghanaian', 'greek', 'grenadian', 'guatemalan', 'guinea-bissauan', 'guinean', 'guyanese', 'haitian', 'herzegovinian', 'honduran', 'hungarian', 'i-kiribati', 'icelander', 'indian', 'indonesian', 'iranian', 'iraqi', 'irish', 'israeli', 'italian', 'ivorian', 'jamaican', 'japanese', 'jordanian', 'kazakhstani', 'kenyan', 'kittian and nevisian', 'kuwaiti', 'kyrgyz', 'laotian', 'latvian', 'lebanese', 'liberian', 'libyan', 'liechtensteiner', 'lithuanian', 'luxembourger', 'macedonian', 'malagasy', 'malawian', 'malaysian', 'maldivan', 'malian', 'maltese', 'marshallese', 'mauritanian', 'mauritian', 'mexican', 'micronesian', 'moldovan', 'monacan', 'mongolian', 'moroccan', 'mosotho', 'motswana', 'mozambican', 'namibian', 'nauruan', 'nepalese', 'new zealander', 'nicaraguan', 'nigerian', 'nigerien', 'north korean', 'northern irish', 'norwegian', 'omani', 'pakistani', 'palauan', 'panamanian', 'papua new guinean', 'paraguayan', 'peruvian', 'polish', 'portuguese', 'qatari', 'romanian', 'russian', 'rwandan', 'saint lucian', 'salvadoran', 'samoan', 'san marinese', 'sao tomean', 'saudi', 'scottish', 'senegalese', 'serbian', 'seychellois', 'sierra leonean', 'singaporean', 'slovakian', 'slovenian', 'solomon islander', 'somali', 'south african', 'south korean', 'spanish', 'sri lankan', 'sudanese', 'surinamer', 'swazi', 'swedish', 'swiss', 'syrian', 'taiwanese', 'tajik', 'tanzanian', 'thai', 'togolese', 'tongan', 'trinidadian/tobagonian', 'tunisian', 'turkish', 'tuvaluan', 'ugandan', 'ukrainian', 'venezuelan', 'vietnamese', 'welsh', 'yemenite', 'zambian', 'zimbabwean']
 }
];
each title in nationalityList
    +e('option').select--list= val(value = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий вариант:

```
- var nationalityList = [{title: 'Afghan', value: 'afgan'}, {title: 'American', value: 'american'}, {title: 'Angolan', value: 'Angolan'}, {title: 'Austrian', value: 'astrian'}];

select#nationality.select(name='nationality')
  each item in nationalityList
    - const {title, value} = item
    option.select--list(value= value)= title
```

Если у вас имена равны значению и так будет всегда, то может сделать обычный массив одномерный, без объектов:

```
- var nationalityList = ['afgan', 'american', 'angolan', 'astrian'];

select#nationality.select(name='nationality' multiple)
  each value in nationalityList
    option.select--list(value= value)= value
```

Добавить в CSS:

```
.select {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}    

.select--list {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Макеты оставил тут: https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/MWWPLwR